# Aptana 3.6 not showing connections

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have just update aptana into the 3.6 version but I have lost all connections that I had in my projects. Also, making new projects just won't show the connections row anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have received an answer in the ticket system of Aptana. In order to see the connections again you have to change the project format from PHP or anything that you have activated into Web. Only that. It doesn't make a lot of sense, but that's how it works now.

To change that you have to go to properties of the project -> project natures and check only Web and make it primary. All the rest of natures must be unchecked.

Comment: For Aptana using Mac OSX this helped me. On Windows I noticed recently my connections were gone as well. Opening the Connection Manager and just Apply the settings was enough to suddenly restore the connections.

Comment: Selecting Properties > Project natures only reads me the error 'The currently displayed page contains invalid values' and there is no option to select anything. (OSX)

Answer (score 4):

1. go to properties of the project -> project natures
2. check only Web and make it primary
3. All the rest of natures must be unchecked
4. Click Ok
5. go to properties of the project -> project natures
6. check PHP (Web should still be checked and set to primary)
7. Click Ok

connections now appear in my project explorer and my php files are still indexed

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (Maverick).

If you click on down arrow (V) to right of Project Explorer tab and tick projects they should show up.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Sorry, missed a few steps in my rush to avert disaster! :)

Comment: Um, didn't work for me... well... I'll have to search for another option to Aptana until they fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Patroklo, What kind of projects is the connections missing? I believe in Aptana Studio 3.6.0, the connections are available only to Web Project.

If the primary nature of the project is set to Web, then the connections would show up in the Project/App Explorer. An alternative/workaround in your case might be to set the primary nature of the project to Web (only if it does not have any other side effects).

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on this page and nothing worked (OS X). The solution that worked was still pretty simple, so hopefully it helps someone else.

[image]

Right Click "Connections" and select "Properties".

[image]

The connection I had that was not showing local path was set to "Filesystem," but simply checking "Project" fixed everything (it's more logical too... not sure why it selected "Filesystem" this time as it's typically been set to "Project" in the past).

Answer (score 0):

I right-clicked each specific connection, clicked `Properties`, and then clicked the `Test` button on the **Edit the FTP connection** dialog. After it succeeded I was able to click `OK` and then the connections worked properly.